# counting and joining serialized data with mysql

Tags: mysql

A database that I'm using has two tables that are linked with serialized (convoluted) data.  The first table is:

```
Table1
CarID  Car
1      BMW
2      Porsche
3      Lexus
```

The second table is:

```
Table2
ColorID Value
1       a:@!"1",asf@"2"
2       b:af"3", asf"1"
3       a:2f"1",asfl@"3"
```

The numbers inside the double quotes refers to the CarID in Table1. It's quite convoluted, but it's part of software and I can't change the database structure.

What I need to do is create a query that figures out how many times each car is linked in Table2.  In this case the output would be:

```
BMW - 3
Porsche - 1
Lexus - 2
```

Is there a query that will do this?

Comment: very bad table structure :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't change your data structure... you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  Table1.CarID,
  Table1.Car,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table2.Value LIKE CONCAT('%"', Table1.CarID, '"%')
GROUP BY
  Table1.CarID,
  Table1.Car
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dce10f/2).